# Sort ints from a txt file

Tags: c, file, sorting, malloc

I need to sort ints from a file in ascending order and print them to the standard output. I can't modify the structure of the file.

The txt file looks like this:

```
41
65
68
35
51
```

...(one number in a row)

My program works just fine for small files, but I have to optomize it for larger files (like 3 million numbers) using `malloc`, but don't know exactly where and how. I'd like to ask for help in this. (I'm a beginner)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER 100000

int sort(int size, int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) 
            {
                int swap = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *filename = argv[1];

    char s[20];

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Input then name of a .txt file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Can't open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    int arr[BUFFER];

    int i = 0;
    int size = 0;

    while ((fgets(s, BUFFER, fp)) != NULL)
    {

        s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';

        arr[i] = atoi(s);
        ++i;
        ++size;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    sort(size, arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are bubble sorting 3 million numbers, you have more to worry about than just how to store them while sorting them all. A better sorting algorithm is likely on the menu. Regardless, make `arr` dynamic, ideally matching the number of items, and if you really want to get fancy, expansive as you read more and more numbers. Refer to your curriculum text on dynamic memory management.

Comment: Use radix sort instead of bubble sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program could look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int numcompar(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *x = a;
    const int *y = b;
    // it is tempting to return *x - *y; but undefined behavior lurks
    return *x < *y ? -1 : *x == *y ? 0 : 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
         // TODO: handle error
         abort();
    }
    char *filename = argv[1];
    // open the file
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        abort();
    }

    // this will be our array
    // note realloc(NULL is equal to malloc()
    int *arr = NULL;
    size_t arrcnt = 0;

    // note - I am using fscanf for simplicity
    int temp = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp) == 1) {
        // note - reallocating the space each number for the next number
        void *tmp = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * (arrcnt + 1));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            free(arr);
            fclose(fp);
            abort();
        }
        arr = tmp;
        // finally assignment
        arr[arrcnt] = temp;
        arrcnt++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // writing sorting algorithms is boring
    qsort(arr, arrcnt, sizeof(*arr), numcompar);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrcnt; ++i) {
       printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
}
```

Note that reallocating for one `int` at a time is inefficient - `realloc` is usually a costly function. The next step would be to keep the number of the size of the array and "used" (assigned to) elements of the array separately and reallocate the array by a ratio greater then 1. There are voices that prefer to use the golden ratio number in such cases.

Comment: reallocating the array 3 million times might be a tad inefficient :)

Comment: Och, forgot to change to `argv[1]`. It is inefficient, but I usually trust the implementation that overallocates anyway.

Comment: Implementations overallocate, but not necessarily in a geometrical fashion. Regarding efficiency, only careful benchmarking would tell, and only for a specific system.

Comment: 1.625 is close enough to the golden ratio :)

Answer (score 1):

To read an undetermined number of entries from the input file, you can allocate and reallocate an array using `realloc()` as more entries are read. For better performance it is recommended to increase the allocated size by a multiple instead of increasing linearly, especially one entry at a time.

Your sorting routine is inappropriate for large arrays: insertion sort has quadratic time complexity, so it might take a long time for 3 million items, unless they are already sorted. Use `qsort()` with a simple comparison function for this.

Here is a modified program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int compare_int(const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    int a = *(const int *)pa;
    int b = *(const int *)pb;
    // return -1 if a < b, 0 if a == b and +1 if a > b
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Input then name of a .txt file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Can't open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[80];
    size_t n = 0, size = 0;
    int *array = NULL;

    /* read the numbers */
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        if (n == size) {
            /* increase size by at least 1.625 */
            size_t newsize = size + size / 2 + size / 8 + 32;
            int *newarray = realloc(array, newsize * sizeof(*array));
            if (newarray == NULL) {
                printf("cannot allocate space for %zu numbers\n", newsize);
                free(array);
                fclose(fp);
                exit(1);
            }
            array = newarray;
            size = newsize;
        }
        array[n++] = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    /* sort the array */
    qsort(array, n, sizeof(*array), compare_int);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot to understand it!